# Crash with a ListView adapter and ViewHolders

Tags: android, listview

Below is the code of my adapter class for a listview in a game on Android
The listview displays 3 types of row :
1) completed level
2) in progress level
3) locked level

I have tried to use the recycler to reduce memory leak as much as possible.
When using this code, I have a crash (see below). the crash happens when I am scrolling down the list and I encounter a locked level in the list. Displaying the inprogress levels work fine.
I think I am doing something wrong with the classes of the holders, but I don't know what.
Thanks for watching this case.

The crash below:

```
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.Adptr_List$ViewHolderInProgress cannot be cast to com.Adptr_List$ViewHolderLocked
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at com.Adptr_List.getView(Adptr_List.java:302)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:636)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5040)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4197)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    01-06 17:11:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(2943):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code of my class below:

```
public class Adptr_List extends ArrayAdapter<Child_Level> {

Context context;

int globalshpsfound = 0;
int currentlvlshpsfound = 0;

class ViewHolderComplete
{
    public TextView tvtitle;
    public TextView tvsubtitle;
    public ProgressBar pb;
    public TextView shpprogress;

    public ViewHolderComplete(
            TextView tvtitle,
            TextView tvsubtitle, 
            ProgressBar pb,
            TextView shpprogress) {
    }       
}

class ViewHolderInProgress
{
    public TextView tvtitle;
    public TextView tvsubtitle;
    public ProgressBar pb;
    public TextView shpprogress;
    public TextView tvPlay;

    public ViewHolderInProgress(
            TextView tvtitle,
            TextView tvsubtitle, 
            ProgressBar pb,
            TextView shpprogress,
            TextView tvPlay) {
    }
}

class ViewHolderLocked
{
    public TextView tvtitle;
    public TextView tvsubtitle;
    public TextView tvmontounlock;

    public ViewHolderLocked(
            TextView tvtitle,
            TextView tvsubtitle, 
            TextView tvmontounlock) {
    }
}

//Initialize adapter
public Adptr_List(Context context, int resource, List<Child_Level> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);

    SharedPreferences sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());   

    globalshpsfound = sPrefs.getInt("globalshpsfound", 0);          
}    


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{               
    SharedPreferences sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()); 

    final Child_Level l = getItem(position);

    currentlvlshpsfound = sPrefs.getInt("foundshps_lvl_"+l.lvlid, 0);
    globalshpsfound = sPrefs.getInt("globalshpsfound", 0);

    // COMPLETE
    if (sPrefs.getInt("foundshps_lvl_"+l.lvlid, 0) == l.shpamount) {

        ViewHolderComplete holdercomplete;   
        View resultview;
        View myconvertview;

        if(convertView==null){

            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflt_lvl_complete, null);                              

            //using the ViewHolder pattern to reduce lookups
            holdercomplete = new ViewHolderComplete(
                    (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel_title),
                    (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel_subtitle),
                    (ProgressBar) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.pbLevel_progress),
                    (TextView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel_progress));

            viewGroup.setTag(holdercomplete);
            resultview = viewGroup;
        }

        else{
            holdercomplete = (ViewHolderComplete) convertView.getTag();
            resultview=convertView;
        }


        // ...here iam setting text and images

        return resultview;
        }

    // IN PROGRESS
    else if (sPrefs.getInt("globalshpsfound", 0)>=l.shptounlock || 
            (sPrefs.getBoolean("bought_lvl_"+l.lvlid, false)==true)){

        ViewHolderInProgress holderinprogress; 
        View resultview;
        View myconvertview;

        if(convertView==null){

            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflt_lvl_inprogress, null);


            //using the ViewHolder pattern to reduce lookups
            holderinprogress = new ViewHolderInProgress(
                    (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel_title),
                    (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel_subtitle),
                    (ProgressBar) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.pbLevel_progress),
                    (TextView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel_progress),
                    (TextView) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel_play));


            viewGroup.setTag(holderinprogress);
            resultview = viewGroup;
        }

        else {
            holderinprogress = (ViewHolderInProgress) convertView.getTag();
            resultview=convertView;
        }

        // ...here iam setting text and images

        return resultview;
        }   



    // LOCKED
    else {
        ViewHolderLocked holderlocked;  
        View resultview;
        View myconvertview;

        if(convertView==null){

            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflt_lvl_locked, null);                

            //using the ViewHolder pattern to reduce lookups
            holderlocked = new ViewHolderLocked(
                    (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel_title),
                    (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel_subtitle),
                    (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel_montounlock));
            //holderlocked = new ViewHolder();


            viewGroup.setTag(holderlocked);
            resultview = viewGroup;
        }

        else{
            holderlocked = (ViewHolderLocked) convertView.getTag();
            resultview=convertView;
        }

        // ...here iam setting text and images

        return resultview;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution using getitemviewtype:

```
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {


    SharedPreferences sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()); 

    if (sPrefs.getInt(somedata stored in sharedpref) 
        return 0;

    else if (somedata stored in sharedpref) 
        return 1;

    else 
        return 2;
}
```

apparently the pb was caused by the mix between sharedprefs data and the child view for each row of the adapter.
For some reason, mixing them within the getview didn't work, but seperating them with getitemviewtype worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the method `getViewTypeCount` and return the number of different cell types, in your case 3.

Detailed answer here :

[Android ListView with different layouts for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row)

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately this doesn't work, after adding @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }

Comment: Have you implemented getItemViewType() as well ?

Comment: I didn't yesterday, but I did this morning and indeed using getitemviewtype helped finding the solution. I have detailed the solution in an auto answer, otherwise I would have accepted yours. Thank you for your help and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use only single ViewHolder. Leave some of the fields empty in some cases but keep it same.
Don't return different type of ViewHolder from same function.

Comment: thanks for your answer; unfortunately, it doesn't work, the layout specific to the locked level doesn't get inflated. Instead, the layout that gets always inflated is inprogress.